# Confused over a statement regarding power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The statement given is "P(A) is a countable set for some A." where A is any set and P(A) is a power set of A.

Now I know that P(A) can never be countably infinite for any A but P(A) can be finite for some A.

May be since English is not my first language I'm struggling to answer whether the given statement is true or false.

I tried rewriting that statement as follows:

"P(A) is a finite or countably infinite set for some A."

Is it safe now to declare this statement to be true because the 'or' inside the statement can clear our way towards finiteness?

I wrote down contrapositive statement too:

"P(A) is neither finite nor countably infinite for all A."

This version seems true since P(A) can be uncountable.

So I think the given statement is true.

PS: I was taught that the word countable is same as 'finite or countably infinite'.

Comment: Yes, in current English usage, "countable" does include "finite".

Comment: This is not an "if-then"-statement, at least not as it stands, so talking about contrapositive doesn't make that much sense.

Comment: @paul I'm concerned about countably infinite thing. I'm afraid it'll make the given statement false.

Comment: @paulgarrett that's not universal; some texts (Rudin, for example) distinguish between *countable* and *at most countable*.

Comment: @Arthur let's consider "Johnny is absent on some days". Then won't it be same as "Johnny is never present on all days?"

Comment: The statement is true but misleading.  Everything finite is countable.  And being uncountable implies infinite. (finite things can't be uncountable).  So it follows "countable" = "finite or countably infinite but not uncountably infinite".  However I think most people (myself included) would read the phrase "countable" and think "countably infinite".  This is especially misleading in "P(A) may be countable" as it takes a (small) bit of thought to realize "P(A) can NOT be countably infinite" (but P(A) may be finite is trivial).

Comment: @fleablood I was taught that countable means 'finite or countably infinite'.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom At most countable is very useful term.  In this case we've got an interesting case where countably infinite is the sole impossibility.  Not sure why the statement says "it may be countable" when "it may be infinite" is a stronger (yet banal) statement.  that "it may not be countably infinite" is far more interesting.

Comment: "I was taught that countable means 'finite or countably infinite'"  In which case the statement *is* true, isn't it.  P(A) can be finite.  "Johnny is never present on all days?" That's amibigous "Johny never(present on all days)" means john is sometimes absent.  "Johny never(present) on all days" means Johny is always absent.  In english speech I think most would take it to mean Johny is always absent.

Comment: @fleablood thank you so much. So only if-then type statements can produce contrapositive statements? That is there is no contrapositive statement in the case of "Johnny is absent on some days."?

Comment: I didn't say that.  The negation of "Johny is absent on some days" is "John is never absent" or "Johny is present on all days".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, while it's possible to find a great variety of usage, to have mathematical language "transform" in fashions contrary to English is a bit perverse. So I imagine in some sources "countable" is short-hand for "countably infinite"? Not ideal, since the negation of "countable" would seem to be "uncountable", which entails "infinite", and so on. Usage that facilitates trick questions is not so good, I think.

Comment: The contrapositive of "Johny is absent on some days" is "It is not the case that Johny is present on all days".

Comment: @fleablood thanks. I could really relate with second version. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement *$P(A)$ is a countable set for some $A$* is true, according to your definitions.  In particular, it suffices to note that if $A =\{1\}$, then $P(A) = \{\emptyset,\{1\}\}$ is finite and therefore countable.

The *negation* of your statement is this: *for all $A$, $P(A)$ is uncountable*.  This statement is false, since it's the negation of a true statement.

Comment: Oh! I confused negation with contrapositive. :(

Comment: The contrapositive of "P(A) is countable for some A" if "It is not true that P(A) is uncountable for all A".

Comment: @fleablood thank you a million times!!!